request to a server from an extension - refresh page after receiving response from server in a browser extension
Maybe I'm missing something, since I'm new to using browser extensions. From an extension a request is made to a proxy, the proxy obtains the response from the final server that responds with the entire HTML document. In the extension I receive everything, including the html and headers. What do I have to do now with that html? what I want is for the new updated cookies to be installed in the browser.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( async function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("received message:", request.data)//-------------------
    if (request.action === "initAction") {
        try {
            // Make a GET request to the proxy server
            const response = await fetch('http://------/proxy/service1', {
              method: 'GET',
            //   credentials: 'include', // Should I include the credentials?
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
            });
            
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log(response.type);//------response ok, html document

                //***********What should I do with the answer?
                //***********I tried to redirect to a new tab but the new cookies are not added to the browser

              chrome.tabs.create({ url: '---------' }); // Redirect user
            } else {
              console.error('Error proxy:', response.statusText);
              
            }
          } catch (error) {
            sendResponse({ mensaje: "Error" });
          }
          return true; 
    }
});

What is the reason? The company's login credentials are hosted in the proxy. Then, workers only need to refresh the page to receive the cookies and log in.
I tried to redirect to a new tab but the new cookies are not added to the.
